# JQuery script not working, can't find the issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page in which I'm trying to load a JQuery script which cycles through text, I have loaded JQuery in my header here:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var divs = $('div[id^="review-"]').hide(),
       i = 0;

      (function cycle() {
             divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, cycle);

          i = ++i % divs.length;
      })();}
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="review-1">Test 1</div>
<div id="review-2">Test 2</div>
<div id="review-3">Test 3</div>
```

I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong here, any help appreciated.

Comment: your document.ready is not closed. are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: your `cycle` function is not closed.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console? Fix your typos and it seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xg5fguzf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to close your `document.ready` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $('div[id^="review-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

  (function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;
  })();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="review-1">Test 1</div>
<div id="review-2">Test 2</div>
<div id="review-3">Test 3</div>
```